# Login script is redirecting

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, mysqli

I've created a login script which when the users logs in it should redirect them to a different page inside a directory called users however it doesnt seems to be working. Below is my script i have created -

```
<?php

session_start();

$errors = []; 

$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

if(!empty($_POST)) {
if(empty($username)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter a username"; 
    echo "<style type=\"text/css\"> #username { background-color:#F5A9A9;border:1px solid #DF0101; } </style>";
}
if(empty($password)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter a password"; 
    echo "<style type=\"text/css\"> #password { background-color:#F5A9A9;border:1px solid #DF0101; } </style>";
} else {

if(empty($errors)) {
    $dir = dirname("link/tooutside/wroot");
    include($dir . '/directory/myconnect.php');

    $salt = "thisismyhash";
    $hashedpass = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

    $result = mysqli_query($conusers, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$hashedpass'"); 
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'true';
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('Location: users/index.php');
            } else {
                $errors[] = "Your username or password is incorrect"; 
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now if i replace the redirect code with an echo statement the echo statement works but when with the redirect link it doesnt redirect me, it simply stays on the index.php page.

Any ideas?

Comment: any errors? Try using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I must admit im not the best with php, to be honest im just starting out so im struggling to understand where ive gone wrong, ive view your link but am still struggling.

Comment: `header()` HTTP Headers sent directly to your browser, clear the called page that contains this function can not display any data because it is not designed to do that - so it is impossible to make an `echo()` before `header()`

Comment: Oh i see so really i need to remove the echo lines that have the css inside?